# How can I determine what gnome desktop number a gnome terminal is connected to?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

In KDE's Konsole, I can do the following from the terminal:

```
dcop kwin KWinInterface currentDesktop
```

And it will tell me which desktop my terminal is connected to

( per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738059/in-kde-how-can-i-automatically-tell-which-desktop-a-konsole-terminal-is-in/745250#745250 )

How can I determine what desktop number the current gnome terminal in a gnome session is connected to?

Comment: are you particularly looking for a commandline interface?

Comment: Preferably.  Otherwise I can compile some code and have that return a number on the command line.  The problem with compiling code is external dependencies.  We have an old Linux environment and people always post code that depends on new APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per hints on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20530/how-can-i-find-the-location-on-the-desktop-of-a-window-on-the-command-line) and the  XLib variable `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738059/in-kde-how-can-i-automatically-tell-which-desktop-a-konsole-terminal-is-in/740422#740422), I determined that the following would work:

```
% xprop -root | egrep '^_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP'
_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
```